# bash function name with dash is bad pratice?

Tags: bash

Look at these examples

```
# fisrt example
function move_file {
    :
}

# second example
function move-file {
    :
}
```

In the second example the dash is used.
Is it a normal practice or is it a bad practice?
Contraindications?

Comment: You should post this question on [the Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than on SO, it will probably be better received there than here. That said in my experience `_` is used to separate words when you can't use spaces (such as in variable names or function names). `move-file` would seem less natural to most AFAICT.

Comment: Mixed opinions.
I don't think there is a position.
I actually don't see many libraries that name dashed function names.

Comment: I don't believe the opinion is mixed at all. If you've checked the duplicate you've seen that using dashes isn't POSIX-compliant which I feel like is reason enough to avoid them as they don't offer any advantage otherwise. And I believe most `bash` coders wouldn't even think about using them since they are forbidden in variable names where you follow the same "how do I name this thing" train of though